# File paths not working when running from a different directory

Tags: c#

In my project I have 2 files that I load using a C# script, however I am getting a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` when I run the project from anywhere but the project root folder.

For example, if I'm in the project root on the terminal and I run `dotnet run`, the program will run fine but if I run it from the outside the project root with `dotnet run -p (path to .csproj)` I get the exception.

These are the pieces of code used for loading files:

```
_shader = new Shader("shader.vert", "shader.frag");
```

-

```
public Shader(string vertPath, string fragPath)
{
    var shaderSource = LoadSource(vertPath);
    ...
}
```

-

```
private static string LoadSource(string path)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `path`?

Comment: It's the same strings passed to `LoadSource`, they're not modified or anything.

Comment: When I say 'exact value' that means I want you to look in the debug or immediate window and get the value. I don't want you to _describe_ it - but _share_ it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it is searching for those files in the [current directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.currentdirectory?view=netframework-4.8).

You have two options:

1. Set the current directory when the program starts

   ```
   Environment.CurrentDirectory = 
   Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
   ```
2. Use absolute paths

   ```
   var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
   _shader = new Shader(folder + "\shader.vert", folder + "\shader.frag");
   ```

Comment: sorry I accidentally marked as answered but I have to test it tomorrow so it is works I will mark as answered